# HTTP ERROR 500 when running Azure functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I am trying to run my python application as Azure functions. It runs perfectly fine when I use the default/original code.

However, I am having problems when I add a new class. When I run the new code locally, it runs correctly (through "Run and "Debug" as well as http://localhost:7071/api/myapp).

However, when I deploy it, I am getting HTTP 500 error (myapp.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.)

I have the following in the requirement.py

```
azure-functions
u8darts==0.19.0
statsforecast==0.6.0
```

Also, my new class is in a new file. Also, I do Deploy to -> function app.

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share here the python function code?

Answer (score 0):

Well -- it was because one of the python packages was incompatible, after using the older version, the problem was fixed. Thanks!